# MYSQL.connector Python create table returns invalid sintax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am creating table like in tutorial for mysql.connector via dict

```
    TABLES[name] = (
    f"CREATE TABLE `{name}` ("
    "  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `Product name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Seller name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Image link` varchar(255)) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Original price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Discount` varchar(10) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Description` text NOT NULL,"
    "  `Actual price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,"
    "  `product URL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Rating score` decimal(1,15) NOT NULL,"
    "  `Reviews` int(5) NOT NULL,"
    "  `ItemId` int(11) NOT NULL,"
    "  `InStock` int(1) NOT NULL,"
    "  `ColorFamily` int(1) NOT NULL,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")


TABLES[colorname] = (
    f"CREATE TABLE `{colorname}` ("
    "  `item_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,"
    "  `ColorName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,"
    "  `ColorPrice` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,"
    "  PRIMARY KEY (`item_no`)"
    f"  CONSTRAINT `{colorname}_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) "
    f"     REFERENCES `{name}` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
```

and I get

> Creating table Women sunglasses: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,  `Original price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,  `Discount` varchar(10) NOT N' at line 1

> Creating table Women sunglasses colorFamily: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `Women sunglasses colorFamily_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)     ' at line 1

What is not correct there?

Comment: Table and column names should be in backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, Still returns a mistake. Can you have a look?

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of the `PRIMARY KEY` line.

Comment: For the second table - Yes. Thank you. But first table is OK with commas. And returns that error

Comment: near 'NOT NULL,  `Original price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,  `Discount` varchar(10) NOT N' at line 1

Comment: No it isn't. `PRIMARY KEY (\`item_no\`)` should be `PRIMARY KEY (\`item_no\`),`

Comment: You have an extra `)`: `VARCHAR(255))`

Comment: Is it really so hard to look for typos right before the place where it says the error is?

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if you used a triple-quoted string to allow newlines, instead of starting a new string on each line.

Comment: oh!!!!! Thank you. I have spent so much time with those backticks that couldn't see anything. Extra ) !!!!!! Oh, so good it is working )))) Thanks again

Comment: I used this template https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-ddl.html ... Really new to MySQL. In python I always used Postgres and now client wants MySQL

Comment: Postgres or MySQL makes no difference. You can use triple quotes to make a string that can continue over multiple lines.[

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Maybe tutorial makers shall also receive such advice ))